# How to get the information from remote machines and show it on local machine?

Tags: c#, .net, remote-server

I want to create a windows service that can be added/configured in remote machines so that I could call them on local machine in order to get the information (Like, Disk space, CPU utilization, on going Processes etc) from the remote machine without disrupting any ongoing processes on remote machines. How is it possible?

I have tried building this simple code in c# and I am able to get the disk space of my machine in a notepad file but how do I proceed from here is something challenging. Please assist me on this or suggest me better way if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tommos/2011/12/03/enumerating-free-disk-space-on-remote-computers-with-powershell/

Comment: _WMI_ is your friend, as indicated in the link by Rufus